# Is the shear map of a smooth principal bundle always a diffeomorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, principal-bundles

For a Lie group $G$, let $\pi \colon P \rightarrow M$ be a principal $G$ bundle over a smooth manifold $M$. There is a canonical shear map $ S \colon P \times G \rightarrow P \times_{M} P$ defined as $(p,g) \mapsto (p,pg)$. In https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principal+bundle#idea, it is given that for a principal bundle, $S$ is an "isomorphism". Although from the action of $G$ on $P$, I could show that $S$ is bijective and smooth, I am not able to show that the inverse of $S$ is smooth.

**My question:**

Is $S$ always a diffeomorphism or just a bijective smooth map?

Comment: Have you instead tried to show that the differential of the shear map was invertible? The conclusion then follows from the inverse function theorem.

Comment: Thank you, are you saying that from the inverse function theorem it will follow that $S$ is a diffeomorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shear map is a diffeomorphism: A local section $s:U\to P$ induces diffeomorphisms
$$
U\times G\times G\to P_{|U}\times G,\;\;\;\;(x,h,g)\mapsto (s(x)h,g)
$$
$$
U\times G\times G\to (P \times_{M} P)_{|U},\;\;\;\;(x,h,g)\mapsto (s(x)h,s(x)g)
$$

Under this diffeomorphism the shear map becomes

$$
U\times G\times G\to U\times G\times G,\;\;\;\;(x,h,g)\mapsto(x,h,hg)
$$

which has a smooth inverse $(x,h,g)\mapsto(x,h,h^{-1}g)$.

Comment: Thank you, I got it!

Comment: But you showed around a local neighbourhood, can we extend it to the whole ?

Comment: The argument shows that the inverse of the shear map (which you convinced yourself to be bijective) is locally smooth. But smoothness is a local property, so it is also globally smooth.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, I understand.